# How can I 'filter' the content of a file on the filesystem?

Tags: python, macos, git, google-app-engine, fuse

I'd like to make it so that when I'm running dev_appserver.py or appcfg.py (executables used by Google AppEngine), they saw my source files with the API keys and other sensitive data they need to contain in order to run, but I'd like to avoid including that information in my git repo.

Right now I have a script that uses the watchdog python library to watch for filesystem changes, pick up the file that changed, process it, and copy it to the directory where I'm running appcfg.py or dev_appserver.py, but this feels really klunky. Is there a better way to do this?

Ideally, the solution would work on both linux and Mac OS X, and ideally, it wouldn't involve FUSE, though if that's really the way to do it, I guess I'll have to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a file to your git repo called `settings.py.dist` that contains a list of necessary keys. Something like:

```
SOME_KEY = ''
ANOTHER_KEY = ''
```

Then copy it to `settings.py` and fill in the keys. Do not add `settings.py` to your git repo. Add `settings.py` to `.gitignore`.

Comment: This is definitely a simpler way of doing what I want -- but I eventually want to do more complex substitution, I believe.